# Make a backup folder read-only but otherwise preserve permissions?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, rsync

In Linux I use `rsync -a --delete /some-path/source/ /some-path2/destination/` to backup the folder `source/` to `destination/`. I want of course to preserve the permissions of all files in `source/`, which is why I use the `-a` flag. However, it's dangerous to leave `destination` with read-write access. Somehow, I want all files in `destination` to retain the permissions of `source`, but I want to leave the regular user with only read access (such that I avoid any accidental modifications). How can I do this?

Comment: Is your destination on an alternate filesystem?  You may want to consider remounting read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're sharing the destination folder to regular users, you could make the 'share' read-only.  Most common protocols allow that... SMB, NFS, etc.

Comment: Yes, it's an external drive with ext4 file system. How can I make sure that when I plug the drive in, Linux (Ubuntu) mounts the drive as read-only by default?

Comment: Off the top of my head:
mount -o ro -t ext4 /dev/sdX1 /some-path2/destination
(where X is your enumerated drive letter)

Comment: Yes, but that's not by default - is it? I want to plug in the backup volume and have it mounted read-only by Ubuntu by default

Comment: But that won't let you backup to it.  So you really need to 'share' the drive as read-only.  How are users accessing this?

Comment: I want the drive to be read-write for root, but read-only for other users.

Comment: How will your users be accessing this? Over SMB/SSH/NFS?

Comment: It's just an external hard drive that I mount locally to my computer. All I want is that when I plug it into my computer, as a normal user I can only look at the contents (read-only access). But for backups that I do by running `rsync` as `root`, I can write into the file (because `root` has read-write access)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve file permissions the only way to prevent write access is at the mount level. As said above. If you only plug it into a few machines you could write a script to mount ro based on the UUID.

Otherwise you will have to

```
chmod -r 444
```